# Erlang : JSON List to JSON List

Tags: json, erlang, mochijson2

I have a list of JSON objects (received from a nosql db) and want to remove or rename some keys.  And then I want to return data as a list of JSON objects once again.

This [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739384/decode-json-with-mochijson2-in-erlang/2740461#2740461) provides a good sense of how to use mochijson2.  And I'm thinking I could use a [list comprehension](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#list-comprehensions) to go through the list of JSON objects.

The part I am stuck with is how to remove the key for each JSON object (or proplist if mochijson2 is used) within a list comprehension.  I can use the [delete function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html#delete-2) of proplists.  But I am unsuccessful when trying to do that within a list comprehension.

Here is a bit code for context :

```
A = <<"[{\"id\": \"0129\", \"name\": \"joe\", \"photo\": \"joe.jpg\"  }, {\"id\": \"0759\", \"name\": \"jane\", \"photo\": \"jane.jpg\"  }, {\"id\": \"0929\", \"name\": \"john\", \"photo\": \"john.jpg\" }]">>. 
Struct = mochijson2:decode(A). 
{struct, JsonData} = Struct,
{struct, Id} = proplists:get_value(<<"id">>, JsonData),
```

Any suggestions illustrated with code much appreciated.

Comment: I should be A = <<"[{\"id\": \"0129\", \"name\": \"joe\", \"photo\": \"joe.jpg\"  }, {\"id\": \"0759\", \"name\": \"jane\", \"photo\": \"jane.jpg\"  }, {\"id\": \"0929\", \"name\": \"john\", \"photo\": \"john.jpg\" }]">>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lists:keydelete(Key, N, TupleList) to return a new tuple list with certain tuples removed. So in the list comprehension, for each entry extract the tuple lists (or proplists), and create a new struct with the key removed:

```
B = [{struct, lists:keydelete(<<"name">>, 1, Props)} || {struct, Props} <- Struct].
```

gives:

```
[{struct,[{<<"id">>,<<"0129">>},
          {<<"photo">>,<<"joe.jpg">>}]},
 {struct,[{<<"id">>,<<"0759">>},
          {<<"photo">>,<<"jane.jpg">>}]},
 {struct,[{<<"id">>,<<"0929">>},
          {<<"photo">>,<<"john.jpg">>}]}]
```

and

```
iolist_to_binary(mochijson2:encode(B)).
```

gives:

```
<<"[{\"id\":\"0129\",\"photo\":\"joe.jpg\"},{\"id\":\"0759\",\"photo\":\"jane.jpg\"},{\"id\":\"0929\",\"photo\":\"john.jpg\"}]">>
```

By the way, using the lists/* tuple lists functions are much faster, but sometimes slightly less convenient than the proplists/* functions: http://sergioveiga.com/index.php/2010/05/14/erlang-listskeyfind-vs-proplistsget_value/